# Обновление части страницы

Tags: javascript, php

Всем привет.

Есть страница `test.php`, внутри страницы есть "код", который нужно заменить на "код 2", потом на "код 3", и опять на "код 1", причем содержимое кода мне заранее не известно. Можно ли такое реализовать через JS ?

```
<?
// код страницы
..
// код который меняется
..
// код страницы
?>
```

Comment: Что Вы хотите сделать на самом деле? Вероятнее всего Вы хотите решить какую-то другую Вашу проблему неверным путем.

Comment: Посмотри про Ajax может это будет и ответ на твой не понятный вопрос)

Comment: Наверно нечто вроде пользователь вводит в форме php-код, жмет выполнить и код выполняется на сервере? Других причин по которым код изначально неизвестен не существует.

Comment: ну, господа, представьте себе что то вроде ... слайдшоу, или прзентации (ближе к ней), вот это и пытаюсь реализовать. слайдшоу в инете есть, но скринить страницу и делать слайдшоу - это изврат. на месте кода будет скорее всего iframe или table

Comment: Насколько понимаю JS может динамически создать код функции и выполнять его.

Comment: код заранее из вестен, и динамически его промисывать не нужно, нужно только заменять его ... по щелчку или через опр. интервал времени

Comment: И все равно я отказываюсь понимать зачем заменять код на сервере.

Comment: @frank, "из вестен" это надо понимать **известен** ? 

Тогда в чем проблема ? У Вас на странице есть функции на JS f1, f2 ... fn. 

Ну, и вызывайте их "по щелчку или через опр. интервал времени".

Comment: Ну что вам помог хоть один из предложенных ответов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
#krutilka > div{display:none}
</style>

<div id="krutilka">
    <div>Код</div>
    <div><img src="164.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div><div>lalala</div></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var k = document.getElementById('krutilka'), d = k.getElementsByTagName('div'), dl = d.length;
var els = [];
// получаем коллекцию элементов
for(var i = 0; i < dl; ++i){
    if(d[i].parentNode == k)
        els[els.length] = d[i];
}

function turn(n){
    n = n%els.length;
    (els[n-1] || els[els.length-1]).style.display = 'none';
    els[n].style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function(){turn(n+1);}, 3000); // 3000 - задержка в миллисекундах
}
turn(0); // 0 - индекс начального элемента
</script>
```

Стандартная крутилка.

Comment: спасибо огромное, супер вестчъ!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contaner">
</div>
<script>
n=-1;
var cod=new Array();
cod[0]="код1";
cod[1]="код2";
cod[2]="код3";
var div=document.getElementById("contaner");
var interval=setInterval(func,1000);
function func(){
  n==cod.length?n=-1:n++;
  div.innerHTML=cod[n];
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: решение классное, но только подставив код - он показывает код, и после всего пишет "undefined" ... потом опять начинает крутить с начала. вот если это слово убрать ( "undefined" ), идеально

Comment: А я не учёл счас исправлю...

Comment: Теперь идеально :)